# Can I make this Linq to EF more efficient?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I have a design where we store answers to scripts's questions by given users.
One script can have many questions and each question can be answered multiple times by a given user.

The MS SQL tables look (removing extra details) more or less like:

```
-Scripts
ScriptId int (PK, identity)

-ScriptQuestions
ScriptId int    (PK)
QuestionId int  (PK)

-Questions
QuestionId int (PK, identity)
QuestionText varchar

-Answers
AnswerId int (PK, identity)
QuestionId int
UserId  int
AnswerText varchar
```

I would like to query this database for a given script and a given user and obtain all questions and the last answer provided for each question (if any).
In T-SQL  I would do something like this:

```
SELECT 
    sq.QuestionId,
    q.QuestionText,
    la.AnswerText   
FROM    
    ScriptQuestions sq
        ON s.ScriptId = sq.ScriptId
    INNER JOIN Questions q
        ON sq.QuestionId = q.QuestionId
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
            SELECT
                QuestionId,
                AnswerText
            FROM Answers
            WHERE AnswerId IN (
                        SELECT 
                            MAX(AnswerId) LastAnswerId
                        FROM Answers
                        WHERE UserId = @userId
                        GROUP BY QuestionId
                    )
            ) la
        ON q.QuestionId = la.QuestionId
WHERE
    sq.ScriptId = @scriptId
```

(untested, but I think it's close to what I would do)

I am using LinqToEF on an MVC 3 application, and to get those results I used:

```
        var questions = from sq in script.ScriptQuestions
                        select new QuestionsAnswers
                                   {
                                       QuestionId = sq.QuestionId,
                                       QuestionText = sq.Question.QuestionText,
                                       LastAnswer = sq.Question.Answers
                                           .Where(a => a.UserId == userId)
                                           .OrderByDescending(a => a.AnswerId)
                                           .Select(a => a.AnswerText)
                                           .FirstOrDefault()
                                   };
```

And I do get the same results BUT when I run the Intellitrace profiler from VS 2010 I can see that linq translates this into sending a `SELECT` statement for EVERY QUESTION on the script and then ANOTHER `SELECT` statement for every answer. So if the scripts has 20 questions, it would be querying the database at least 40 times instead of sending just one SQL statement as above.

I tried to change the way I create my LinqToEF statement but I was not able to overcome the n `SELECT` statements issue.

This cannot be the right way, or is it?

Comment: I think I rather join those tables together in the query. `from sq in script.Sqriptquestions join a in script.Answers on a.questionid equals sq.questionid where userId == a.UserId select new .. { }`  . (Not exactly but the idea). Linq will filter out without your extra inner query (which in fact run once per item in scriptQuestions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that your query uses LINQ to Objects in memory in combination with lazy loading of the navigation properties because your query starts with `script.ScriptQuestions` which is apparently not an `IQueryable`. So the collection is iterated in memory and for every entry you access the `sq.Question` and `sq.Question.Answers` navigation properties. If lazy loading is enabled each time you access these properties a new query is issued to the DB to populate the properties. Your filter on the `sq.Question.Answers` collection is performed in memory on the full collection.

You can try to change it the following way:

```
    var questions = from sq in context.ScriptQuestions
                    where sq.ScriptId == script.ScriptId
                    select new QuestionsAnswers
                               {
                                   QuestionId = sq.QuestionId,
                                   QuestionText = sq.Question.QuestionText,
                                   LastAnswer = sq.Question.Answers
                                       .Where(a => a.UserId == userId)
                                       .OrderByDescending(a => a.AnswerId)
                                       .Select(a => a.AnswerText)
                                       .FirstOrDefault()
                               };
```

This should be only one single database query because now it's LINQ to Entities with `IQueryable`.

Comment: Yes! You nailed it. Much better now, it even uses OUTER APPLY to improve performance. thanks a lot.